# How can I make rounded border with CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I mean the green rounded border that's outside the check icon. Currently, I have the entire circle around the check but I'm really confused about how to introduce that little cut in the top-left corner.

Here's the code:

```html
<div v-if="verified" class="flex justify-center items-center border-3 border-green rounded-full">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 15 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-3 h-3">
          <path
            d="m10.51 4.525-3.6 3.6-1.65-1.65a.636.636 0 0 0-.9.9l2.1 2.1a.636.636 0 0 0 .9 0l4.05-4.05a.636.636 0 0 0-.9-.9z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
        </svg>
</div>
```

There's the SVG, and I'm using Tailwind, so the border class is right there in the `<div>`. Any suggestion/help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can look for: stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset or even cooler using css border-image with an svg border or you you could simply add some content with pseudo elements. I think there is no right or wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```css
#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-left: 5px solid white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

You just have to change rotate value, if you want to hide some other portions.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a solution how i would code it with tailwind

https://play.tailwindcss.com/OLqtK5HSba

```html
<div class="p-24 flex items-center justify-center">
  <div class="flex relative justify-center items-center w-auto border-[3px] border-green-400 rounded-lg px-8 py-3 
  before:block before:absolute before:-left-[3px] before:-top-[3px] before:w-[calc(50%+3px)] before:h-[calc(50%+3px)] z-10 before:bg-white">
    <span class="relative z-20">Your Button</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  If the link is down the answer becomes useless. Furthermore I good answer explains how the goal is achieved.